# Devise params auto adds weird data in sign up registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, devise, registration

My application using vue3 to build devise sign up page and i'm using axios request to create user.
In registration controller, i found that params has added added an extra field name called `registration` data.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"user"=>{"name"=>"name", "email"=>"mail", "phone"=>"123",  "type"=>0}, "controller"=>"users/registrations", "action"=>"create", "registration"=>{"user"=>{"name"=>"name", "email"=>"mail", "phone"=>"123", "type"=>0}}}
```

It contains params[:user], that looks weird to me. Can someone explain?

```
"registration"=>{"user"=>{"name"=>"name", "email"=>"mail", "phone"=>"123", "type"=>0}
```

My form code:

```
 methods: {
    signUp: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let user_params = {
        user: {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          phone: this.phone,
          type: this.type,
        }
      }

      this.$http.post('/users', user_params)
        .then(response => {
          this.$emit('next');
        }).catch(err => {
          this.error = err.response.data;
      });
    },


  }
```

And in view

```
<form>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-10 mt-5 mx-auto text-center">
        <div class="checked-circle mx-auto">
          <img :src="checkedStepImg" class="w-100 h-100">
        </div>
        <div class="title mt-5"> Let sign up for your account </div>
        <div class="mt-3 text-red" v-if="error">{{ error }} </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-6">
            <input class="form-control shadow-none rounded-0" placeholder="Name" v-model="name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <input class="form-control shadow-none rounded-0" placeholder="Email" v-model="email">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-text rounded-0">+1</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none rounded-0 bg-white" placeholder="Phone" v-model="phone">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <select class="form-select shadow-none rounded-0" aria-label="Default select example" v-model="type">
              <option value="0" selected> Personal </option>
              <option value="1"> Corporation </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-sm-5 mx-auto btn-box mt-5">
          <button class="btn btn-dark w-100 h-100" @click.prevent="signUp"> Sign up!</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

**That does not happen if i use a normal form devise sign_up**

Comment: Can you show the code for your form?

Comment: I updated it in the question